# HTTP request queue with worker pool

Tags: java, http, queue, pool

I'm developing application in Java which connects to different web-servers via HTTP protocol (sends them request and waits for response). I would like to use pattern with queue and worker pool, so I'd like to know if there any frameworks in Java providing methods for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is a threadpool. It has a queue of tasks and a number of threads working on those tasks. A little bit of googling for "java threadpool" landed me there, might be relevant. http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

Threading can be messy if you aren't careful when designing, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try java queue service like onlinemq.com or SQS